# В приложении используется версия SDK, которая нарушает правила

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, google-play-console, ads

Недавно обновил приложение Flutter с рекламой Appodeal и позже я получил сообщение.

Google Play Console:

Ваше приложение *** (код версии ***) содержит SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk или использует библиотеку, зависящую от SDK, который собирает персональные или конфиденциальные данные, включая, помимо прочего, следующие постоянные идентификаторы: Advertising ID, Android ID, Device Wifi MAC. Согласно правилам в отношении пользовательских данных постоянные идентификаторы устройства не должны быть связаны с личными или конфиденциальными данными пользователя и со сбрасываемыми идентификаторами устройств.

Где я могу найти в моем приложении SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk

app>build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1'
implementation ('com.appodeal.ads:sdk:3.0.0.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'adjust'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'appsflyer'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'firebase'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'facebook_analytics'
}
implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services:firebase:3.0.0.+'
}
```

Как сделать чтобы постоянные идентификаторы устройства не были связаны с личными или конфиденциальными данными пользователя и со сбрасываемыми идентификаторами устройств ?

Как мне решить эту проблему. Нужно ли мне действительно прекратить использовать Appodeal?

Comment: А просто указать в консоли, что вы собираете эти данные, а также отразить это в Privacy Policy ?

Comment: @Style-7 У меня указано и в policy и в опроснике гугл консоли. Но гугл требует от меня дейсивие "ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ДЕЙСТВИЕ. Загрузите новую версию, соответствующую требованиям, и удалите старую."

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://wiki.appodeal.com/ru/android/integration-guide/data-protection/zashchita-dannyh-v-google-play) Appodeal собирает Device ID, но там все мутно описано (ссылаются на Advertising ID), поэтому лучше написать в тех. поддержку и рассказать о результатах здесь

Comment: @Style-7 mytracker выпустил новую версию. Нужно было обновить синхронизацию зависимостей и в новой версии больше не показывает это сообщение гугл мне

Comment: И как решили проблему? Можите подсказать?

Comment: @DadoDavudof https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663727/your-app-includes-non-compliant-sdk-version-com-my-trackermytracker-sdk